# Windows Wiki : Books and Tutorials

Tags: windows

This post is for collecting all the best books and tutorials that exist dealing with [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) specific reverse engineering techniques and concepts. The content will be added to the [Windows wiki](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/windows/info). Any suggestions of books and tutorials should be added into the CW answer. Please do not add any other answers.

---

If you have anything to say about this, post your opinion here :

- [How should book/tutorial questions be dealt with?](https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53/how-should-book-tutorial-questions-be-dealt-with)
- [Lets develop a Tag Wiki format](https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/lets-develop-a-tag-wiki-format)
- If you have something else to say not covered in the above discussions, start a [new meta discussion](https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: already 3 votes to close, leaving this open as a community wiki seems reasonable?

Comment: Why was this question closed. It was proven effective.

Comment: @Mellowcandle: it *is* outside the scope of a Q&A site. Making this entirely CW will allow others to edit away and closing it won't make it go away (unless you'd decide to delete it). Basically we are cheating to have something to reference from tag wikis, but we all know we're cheating, because shopping-list-like questions aren't allowed :)

Comment: I have voted to close as there have been multiple discussions on Meta about this specific issue. [1](http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141/allow-moderated-list-question), [2](http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53/how-should-book-tutorial-questions-be-dealt-with) and [3](http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144/highlighting-the-tag-wikis) regarding issues with Tag Wikis. If we were to follow democratic processes, then the majority opinion was to add this information to the Tag Wikis via a post on Meta (+5 score) and

Comment: not as a separate question on Main (0 score). Meta is for deciding site policies and I believe we should adhere to majority decisions taken there. There was [another post](http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/168/189) by Robert Cartaino that explains in detail the problems with such questions. Also, I do think that we need a list of books and resources and its absolutely great to see the effort being put into this!

Comment: @AshRj: can't you migrate it over to meta?

Comment: @AshRj the link is dead

Comment: @heinrich5991 Which link ?

Comment: @AshRj 'There was <another post> by Robert Cartaino'

Comment: @heinrich5991 It appears to have been deleted by the OP. I will look into it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Books:

- **[Reversing: Secrets of Reverse Engineering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764574817)**, Eldad Eilam
- [**IDA Pro Book, 2nd Edition**](http://nostarch.com/idapro2.htm), Chris Eagle ([book's website](http://www.idabook.com/))
- [**Gray Hat Python**](http://nostarch.com/ghpython.htm), Justin Seitz
- [**Windows Internals, 6th edition**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx)
- [**Windows via C/C++ 5th Ed**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735663777)

## Articles:

## Tutorials:

- [Lena's Reversing 101](http://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.17) — the classic introduction for newbie reverser.
- [The Legend of Random](http://octopuslabs.io/legend/blog/sample-page.html) — list of tutorials and texts to read on RE topics.

## Links:

- [OpenSecurityTraining](http://opensecuritytraining.info/Training.html) — place of great and free online courses to learn, from beginners to hi-level pros.

## Forums:

- <s>[KernelMode](http://www.kernelmode.info/forum/) — here you'll find not only a wide range of topics regarding different parts of RE, but also a great community.</s> (archived)

Comment: I added Windows Internals

Comment: Added 3 links from my answer. :)

Comment: Gray hat python is outdated.

Comment: @Mellowcandle what about assembly language